# libnss3 Update Downgrading Problem

Tags: apt, package-management

I have downgraded `libnss3` on my Ubuntu so I can install Upwork software. I have installed this software successfully. But after this downgrade, I am unable to install any other software on my system.

I am getting the following error:

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f            The following packages have unmet dependencies: 

 aptitude: Depends: libapt-pkg4.12 (>= 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu6) but 1.0.1ubuntu2.11 is installed

Depends: libboost-iostreams1.46.1 (>= 1.46.1-1) but it is not installed

      Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.7 is installed
      Depends: libcwidget3 but it is not installed
      Depends: libept1.4.12 but it is not installed
      Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 is installed
      Depends: libncursesw5 (>= 5.6+20070908) but 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1 is installed
      Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2) but 2.2.10-0.2ubuntu2 is                installed
      Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.6.5) but 3.8.2-1ubuntu2.1 is installed
      Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 is installed
libnss3-nssdb: Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.21-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) but 2:3.19.2-1ubuntu1 is installed
```

Comment: What command did you execute to get this error? Did you try to fix it by executing the command the error message tells you to execute? Should there be an aditional line break in the second line of the code block? Is the thing you downgraded called "libnss3 Update" or "libnss3"? Please try to quote the package name of the package you downgraded (best with code markers: `\`package-name\``) so people will get less confused.

Comment: https://community.upwork.com/t5/Freelancers/upwork-on-Ubuntu-an-unknow-error-has-occurred/td-p/136117/page/2  this is what i have used to downgrade

Comment: Please post the exact commands you used here in your post (you can edit it). Don't just link to some thread where we have to read through all the messages and make a guess which of the commands discussed there you did actually execute.

Comment: sorry for not explaning it in detail. This command i run to downgrade libss3:  sudo apt-get install libnss3=2:3.15.4-1ubuntu7 libnss3-nssdb=2:3.15.4-1ubuntu7 libnss3-1d=2:3.15.4-1ubuntu7 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after doing lot of search what i have resolved it. In dpkg folder, i have file named lock. I have changed the permission of the file and also for dpkg folder. Then i run

```
apt-get install -f
```

now i will be able to install any software.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: this is general advice for any application that needs an earlier, superseded or in other way eccentric library. The libnss3 library and the upwork application are perfectly good examples.

**1. Fix your system**

OK, first thing, undo what you have done. If you have used any apt-pin's then remove them (for libnss3) and then do:

```
apt-get install libnss3
aptitude update; aptitude safe-upgrade
```

Then check that you have the latest up to date version installed:

```
apt-cache policy libnss3
```

or

```
dpkg-query -l libnss3
```

Right, your system is working properly again.

**2. Get upwork working**

Next, get the upwork application working. First, separately download an  earlier version of libnss3 and put this earlier, downgraded version in another directory. I am on debian, so I got the stable package from from https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libnss3 . The place for such libraries is in /usr/local/lib/someDir/ . Once thelibnss3_3.17.2-1.1+deb8u2_i386.deb (say) file is in this directory or in a temp directory, extract its contents out from it:

```
dpkg-deb -x libnss3_3.17.2-1.1+deb8u2_i386.deb
```

and move the libnss3 libraries into your /usr/local/lib/someDir/

```
mv <extractDir>/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nss/*    /usr/local/lib/someDir/
```

which might be

```
mv /usr/local/lib/someDir/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nss/*   /usr/local/lib/someDir/
```

You now have the downgraded libraries in separate directory.   Now you just need to make the upwork application use these libraries.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_NAME=/usr/local/lib/someDir:$LD_LIBRARY_NAME
upwork
```

The better solution is to make a short script called /usr/local/bin/upwork (yes, exactly the same name), then ensure (yes, ensure) that /usr/local/bin/ is in you $PATH *before* /usr/bin. This short script will include

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/someDir:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/bin/upwork 2 >& 1  &
```

make the script executable

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/upwork
```

Your upwork application will now use these downgraded libnss3 libraries.

Comment: thanks for your reply but something else worked for me which i have explained below.